# How do you modify Eclipse IDE tooltip?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

When I'm writing C in Eclipse, sometimes I see an explanation of what the function does. For instance, the tooltip for fopen explains that you can use r for read and w for write.

How do you make this kind of information show up for your own functions? I'd like to be able to make a library and for anyone using it, they could see what the different parameters are for.

Comment: Add a comment before your function declaration, can't remember what format eclipse accepts for c++, might be doxygen?

Comment: @AlanBirtles From what I've read eclipse-cdt only takes doxygen comments from *definitions*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add comments before your function the Eclipse-CDT will automatically pick them up and apply them in the tool tip.